# Click event doesn’t fire after browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I’m currently using [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), a carousel. When the browser is resized below a certain threshold, I have the carousel set to `unslick` (meaning it stops being a carousel and each carousel panel is displayed statically one on top of another). The setting is this:

```
responsive:[{
  breakpoint: 992,
  settings: "unslick"
}]
```

It works great. However, I also have a `.click` function that’s called when an element *in the carousel* is clicked on. Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#linkInCarousel').click(function(){
    console.log('success');
  });
}
```

The `.click` function works on initial loading of the page, but if the page is resized, it no longer does. Any ideas?

Comment: hmm, can you show us the console log?

Comment: I wonder if they're replacing the html, thus losing your event handlers on those DOM elements. Try delegating the events to the document instead, like this: `$(document).on('click', '#linkeInCarousel', function(){})`

Comment: Try using 'on' function:     $('#linkInCarousel').on('click', function(){ .... }

Comment: I've never used the plugin though,I assume that `unslick` removes click event, try `$(window).on("click","#linkInCarousel",function(){console.log("success")})`

Comment: @SpritsDracula .click calls .on, so there's no difference between the two.

Comment: @SprintsDracula that's exactly what `$().click` means

Comment: @yts that did it, thanks!  Maybe you can answer my question so I can mark it as the answer :)

Comment: @pauliwago thanks :) Also added more stuff to make it more like an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin may be replacing the HTML which causes it to lose the event handlers assigned to those DOM elements. Instead, try delegating the events to the document, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '#linkInCarousel', function(){
    console.log('success');
  });
};
```

What this does is lets the document (which never gets removed) handle the event and checks to see if the actual target of the event matches the selector, in this case '#linkInCarousel'. This way, even if the element is added after page load the handler will fire properly.

In general it can be beneficial to use delegation when dealing with a list of elements, so you're only adding one event handler as opposed to creating the handlers for every element. Read more about it [here.](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: @aspiringsoftwaredev I'm glad it helped someone 5 years later!